# Rails 3] About Requiring a Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, require

A Simple Question: When do you have to put 'require gem_name' into a controller? As I've explored quite a few gems, some of them make me put 'require' and others don't. I need some clarification. Are all those instructions that tell me to require a gem outdated?

Could you confirm: having `gem gem_name` in the Gemfile and running `bundle install` is all I need to do for all gems, and placing `require gem_name` isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are adding your required Gems to the Gemfile and running `bundle install`, then you shouldn't add `require gem_name` to the controller file, the Gem will be available for you.